# Merge some commits in pull requests in Github

Tags: git, version-control, github, pull-request

I have created a pull request on Github. I have 2 commits in the pull request. How (if it is possible) can I merge only the first commit, and then create a second pull request for the second commmit.

Ex:
I have a pull request with commits A and B (in that order. B is latest commit). I want to merge only A with one pull request, and then create a separate pull request to merge B. How can this be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Person A has repo A. Person B forks repo A to repo B with the intent of fixing issue 42. Person B creates branch issue42 on repo B, hacks on the issue, and commits it. Person B creates a pull request to person A on repo A for branch bug42.

Now, Person A sees the pull request consists of two commits C1 and C2 and decides they only want C1.

Here, the right thing to do is for Person A to ask Person B to amend their pull request so it only contains C1. This preserves history correctly. So Person B can do something like

```
git branch bug42_c1 bug42^ # create new branch bug42_c1 on the ancestor of the tip of branch bug42
```

Now Person B can submit a pull request for branch bug42_c1.

Hopefully this is a correct understanding of your question. If it is not then consider looking at my answer and seeing how to rephrase your question for increased clarity.

Comment: I think you got the gist of the question, and this should solve the problem. So, Person B will ammend the pull request by creating a new branch.
Here, bug42_c1 will contain commit c1
bug42 will contain c2
Then create separate pull requests?

Comment: Well, bug42 will contain C1 and C2, but you cancel that pull request. bug42_c1 will contain only C1, and you create a new pull request for that branch. In the pull request, refer to the discussion with Person 1 where he/she requested that you amend your pull request.